# qmake install without sdk (Win)

Tags: qt-creator, qmake

I'm using qmake as build system in my project. And not using qt sdk. How correctly install qmake without sdk on clean mashine(win7 + msvc). Simple copy bin, mkspec dirrectories wrong result. I can't speciefied qmake tools in QtCreator (invalid profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this solution](http://cristianadam.blogspot.com/2012/06/portable-qmake.html). Maybe you already test this method. It slightly different from that what you told in question. They use `qt.conf` for something. Sorry I don't know for what purpose

Comment: I'm using qmake for cross build project on Poco framework without UI. And I do not need qt sdk.